# Excel: SUMPRODUCT with wildcard not matching exact cell content

Tags: excel, sumproduct

I would like to make use of SUMPRODUCT depending of an specific identifier (e.g. 01, 02_01 and so on). My solution looks like this so far:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("??",E2:E9)))*F2:F9*G2:G9)`

[image: Minimal Example in Excel]

Now, actually I expected a sum of 1332 matching only line 2 and 7 but it matches all lines. How do I overcome this unwanted behavior? A VBA solution would be fine too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(E2:E9)=2)*F2:F9*G2:G9)`?

Comment: Nah, sadly not the solution for me. I need to match also something like 01_?? or ??_??.

Comment: Well, but I could combine it to: ```=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(E2:E9)=5)*--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("01_??",E2:E9)))*F2:F9*G2:G9)``` but its not a neat solution... :(

Comment: `??` matches any two characters btw.

Comment: I know... I use it within filters every day and filters limit the length with the quantity of wildcards used. Whereas SEARCH() is not length-sensitive and looks for any cell with equal or greater two characters when using ??.

Comment: Pretty much `??` matches any two characters so it'll match the first two characters of *any* cell. `SEARCH` and `??` is not the same as "is the cell 2 characters only". So yeah if you want a specific length, you can use the solution you outlined.

Comment: ...but specifying the length separately is not really neat. :(

Comment: Wait, I can grab the length using a VBA function. That should work if there's so easier solution with excel commands. Thanks a lot so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add something to the front and end to ensure it is looking at the whole and not part:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("|"&"??"&"|","|"&E2:E9&"|")))*F2:F9*G2:G9)
```

[image]

Comment: This is elegant. Thanks so much!